# PHP using imageline and XOR

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I am trying to use the image GD library to draw lines using an XOR filter. I have not been able to find an easy way to do this so a line being drawn "flips" white to black and vice-versus. Any solutions?

Comment: Please explain what an XOR filter is

Comment: @Mark - Instead of copying color of your pen over the color of the point on the canvas where you want to draw, you XOR it with that color and put result there. If you do same thing twice you get same color on the canvas that you was there before you drew anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's not possible to draw the XOR line with built-in `imageline` PHP function. Though you can draw it yourself with `imagesetpixel` and custom line drawing algorithm. For example something like this can work (Bresenham Line Algorythm for PHP):

```
function line($im,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2) {

$deltax=abs($x2-$x1);
$deltay=abs($y2-$y1);

if ($deltax>$deltay) {
 $numpixels=$deltax+1;
 $d=(2*$deltay)-$deltax;
 $dinc1=$deltay << 1; $dinc2=($deltay-$deltax) << 1;
 $xinc1=1; $xinc2=1;
 $yinc1=0; $yinc2=1;
} else {
 $numpixels=$deltay+1;
 $d=(2*$deltax)-$deltay;
 $dinc1=$deltax << 1; $dinc2=($deltax-$deltay)<<1;
 $xinc1=0; $xinc2=1;
 $yinc1=1; $yinc2=1;
}

if ($x1>$x2) {
 $xinc1=-$xinc1;
 $xinc2=-$xinc2;
}

if ($y1>$y2) {
 $yinc1=-$yinc1;
 $yinc2=-$yinc2;
}
$x=$x1;
$y=$y1;

for ($i=0;$i<$numpixels;$i++) {

 $color_current = imagecolorat ( $im, $x, $y );
 $r = ($color_current >> 16) & 0xFF;
 $g = ($color_current >> 8) & 0xFF;
 $b = $color_current & 0xFF;
 $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255 - $r, 255 - $g, 255 - $b);

 imagesetpixel($im,$x,$y,$color);

 if ($d<0) {
  $d+=$dinc1;
  $x+=$xinc1;
  $y+=$yinc1;
 } else {
  $d+=$dinc2;
  $x+=$xinc2;
  $y+=$yinc2;
 }
}
    return ;
}
```

Function perfectly works for images, created from files.

Comment: I discovered that solution on my own, its just reaaaaaly slow. I was hoping someone knew of a quicker solution. (using imageline)